# Refinery asset_helpers not resolved in production/heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, refinerycms

I'm pushing a rails app to Heroku (production) and the asset_helpers in the refinery backend stylesheets aren't being executed. So for example `/assets/refinery/refinery-7fcfa3e350d8ea2e09ea6da68c6e16c9.css` contains the line:

```
#E7682C image_url("refinery/orange_button.png") repeat-x
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm thinking that I just need to add some config to application.rb/production.rb... still researching it

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The above can be solved by including the path 'refinery/refinery.css' in config.assets.precompile in your production.rb.

So my production.rb file now includes the line:

`config.assets.precompile += %w( refinery/refinery.css )`